# Delayed background image rendering on element initially not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a slider, with slide thumbnails hiding at bottom of page. working fiddle:      [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft0ajua5/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    .thumbnails {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 200px;
      display: block;
      bottom: -200px;
    }

    .thumbnails .thumb {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      height: 200px;
      background-size: auto 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 0 0;
      width: 20%;
      background-position: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .thumb_1 {
      background-image: url("img/slide_1.jpg");
    }

    .thumb_2 {
      background-image: url("img/slide_2.jpg");
    }

    .thumb_3 {
      background-image: url("img/slide_3.jpg");
    }

    .thumb_4 {
      background-image: url("img/slide_4.jpg");
    }

    .thumb_5 {
      background-image: url("img/slide_5.jpg");
    }
    .ovl {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-image: url("img/mask.png");
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="thumbnails">
    <div class="thumb thumb_1" data-target="#slide_1">
        <div class="ovl"></div>
        <div class="thumb_text">Slide 1 text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb thumb_2" data-target="#slide_2">
        <div class="ovl"></div>
        <div class="thumb_text">Slide 2 text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb thumb_3" data-target="#slide_3">
        <div class="ovl"></div>
        <div class="thumb_text">Slide 3 text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb thumb_4 active" data-target="#slide_4">
        <div class="ovl"></div>
        <div class="thumb_text">Slide 4 text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb thumb_5" data-target="#slide_5">
        <div class="ovl"></div>
        <div class="thumb_text">Slide 5 text</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var thumbnails = $('.thumbnails');
var open = false;
  $(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    console.log(thumbnails.is(':animated'));
        if (thumbnails.is(':animated')) return;

        var $this = $(this);

        //run thumbnails only, when dots are invisible
          if (($this.height() - e.pageY < 50) && !open) {
            //show thumbnails
            thumbnails.css('bottom', '0').hide();
            thumbnails.slideDown(function() {
              open = true;
            });
          } else if(($this.height() - e.pageY > 200)) {
            //hide thumbnails
            thumbnails.slideUp(function() {
              thumbnails.css('bottom', '-200px').show();
              open = false;
            });
          }
      });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome and IE everything works fine, but in FF (i am using ver. 51.0.1) images seems to have delayed rendering. When I inspect the network traffic, all images are downloaded right after the html. When I move cursor to bottom of page (to display thumbnails) first what I see is the .ovl mask and pictures appear  about 0.5 - 1 s later.

Some solution to make those images visible before thumbnails slide up ?